# hiding an element with javascript, in a modular way

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create some functionality akin to .hide in jquery, but just using plain javascript, here's what I have so far:

```
(function() {

addLoadEventHandler(function() {


        getByName = (function(name){ 
            return document.getElementsByTagName(name)
        })

        hide = (function(){
            return style.display = 'none'

        })

    });

return {

    getByName: getByName,
    hide: hide
};
}());
```

so terribly incomplete, but am I heading along the right track here. Sorry, bit of a noob.

Answer (score 2):

You need context for the hide function. Either you wrap a DOMElement like jQuery does, or you need to pass it in. I'll give examples for both:

```
var incomplete = (function () {

    function hide(DOMElement) {
        DOMElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

    return {
        hide: hide
    };
}());

// use like:
incomplete.hide(document.getElementById("container"));
```

or

```
var incomplete = function (context_element) {
    function hide() {
        context_element.style.display = 'none';
    }

    return {
        hide: hide
    };
};

// use like:
incomplete(document.getElementById("container")).hide();    // like jQuery
```

Comment: I don't _like_ jQuery, I should have put _simalar to_ XD

Answer (score 0):

Sort of, you need to assign it to something

```
mymodule = function () {

        //"private" variables:
        var privateVar = "only from within this module."

        //"private" methods:
       var getByName = function(name){ 
           return document.getElementsByTagName(name)
       }

       hide = function(){
           return style.display = 'none'
       }

       // public interface
        return  {
           getByName: getByName,
           hide: hide           
                }
        };

}(); // the parens here cause the anonymous function to execute and return
```